# Android App not working after changing Target API

Tags: android

I was following a tutorial on [Android Hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) . When I specify the android:targetSdkVersion in the manifest to the latest version, one activity of the class does not work, rest all work perfectly.

Also, 
If I remove the targetSdkVersion from Manifest, it works fine. Can you please help me with this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post your code and what error are you getting from logcat strace.

Comment: you can provide min and max sdk versions.......

Comment: Please specify the class causing issues, and the error it gives you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this tutorial `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />` is defined so please check your targeted version must be higher then it.

Comment: what you did can you tell? @Aneesh

Comment: I've a code which is not related to androidhive but has same error

Comment: I have minSDK 21

Comment: targetSDKVersion 30